# I cannot access my database using docker [Python]

Tags: javascript, python, database, docker

I am not the most knowledgeable on the subject, my friend did the entire Docker setup. I am trying to connect to a Database using Python. This database is accessed by JavaScript, who sends information about clients to the db. However, whenever I try accessing the db through Python:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import psycopg2
import sys
import time

print(sys.path)

load_dotenv()  # Load environment variables from .env file

# Accessing environment variables
DB_NAME = os.getenv("POSTGRES_DB")
DB_USER = os.getenv("POSTGRES_USER")
DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")
DB_HOST = 'db'  # Service name defined in Docker Compose
DB_PORT = "5432"  # Port exposed by PostgreSQL container

def get_users():
    try:
        time.sleep(10)
        # Attempt to establish a database connection
        print(DB_HOST)
        print(DB_NAME)
        print(DB_PASSWORD) 
        print(DB_PORT)
        print(DB_USER)
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=DB_NAME,
            user=DB_USER,
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
            host=DB_HOST,
            port=DB_PORT
        )
        print("Database connection successful")
        
        # Perform database operations
        try:
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
                users = cur.fetchall()
                return users
        except psycopg2.Error as query_error:
            print(f"Failed to query database: {query_error}")
        
        finally:
            # Close the database connection
            conn.close()

    except psycopg2.Error as connection_error:
        print(f"Database connection failed: {connection_error}")
```

I get Database connection failed: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

When I try using the IP address instead of 'db' it works so I know that the access to my .env file is fine. Additionally, the index.js file that accesses the db does:

```
const dbConfig = {
  host: 'db', // the database server
  port: 5432, // the database port
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB, // the database name
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER, // the user account to connect with
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD, // the password of the user account
};
```

And it successfully connects to the db. I am unsure why it is not working. Here is also my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    env_file: .env
    expose:
      - '5432'
    volumes:
      - lab-09-web-services:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init_data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  web:
    image: node:lts
    user: 'node'
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    command: 'npm start'
  python-app:
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - web
# This defines our volume(s), which will persist throughout startups.
# If you want to get rid of a hanging volume, e.g. to test your database init,
# run `docker-compose rm -v`. Note that this will remove ALL of your data, so
# be extra sure you've made a stable backup somewhere.
volumes:
  lab-09-web-services:
```

I have already tried adding a Dockerfile for python and a bunch of different things but everything gets me the exact same error

I have tried multiple approaches with the help of GenAI to no success. I only want to access the db and get the information I need

Comment: Are you running your Python code separately rather than through the compose file? Note that the hostname being `db` would only work if you run your Python app in docker compose (I do see a `python-app` service in your compose file). Otherwise given you've exposed the port you can access it using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: When I try running localhost I get:

Database connection failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Also, I am only running this code locally now, in the future I plan to run it using a server, would localhost work for that?